# How to resolve this issue, I want to make my image circular using tailwind css?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

[image]

```
<div className='flex justify-between w-full'>
   <div className='px-1 w-full'>
       <img
         src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1566275529824-cca6d008f3da?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8NXx8cGhvdG98ZW58MHx8MHx8fDA%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60'
         alt='Pic'
         className='h-10 w-10 rounded-full border-2 w-full'
        />
   </div>
   <p className='border-2'><span className='text-lg font-semibold'>dottt</span>  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
 </div>
```

how to make this(small) image circular and text container align with same & i'm using tailwind css?

Comment: try `rounded-full aspect-square object-cover` on the <img>, Created a tailwind playground FYR, https://play.tailwindcss.com/Qkd9DV5ggj

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem comes from the fact that you've set the width of the image twice. `w-full w-10` and one them getting overridden by the other.

You can set `rounded-full max-w-full h-auto` to make your image circular. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

it because the width is set again to w-full, this make the h is not same as w, then the image streched to w-full and h-10. instead, you can use w-10 only if you want to set the w and h in the same time as your h is 10. in other side, you can use `w-full aspect-square object-cover` if you want to set the w-full and the h same as w.

you can see the example [here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/L1kYHksIxh)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div className='flex justify-between w-full'>
   <div className='px-1 w-full'>
       <img
         src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1566275529824-cca6d008f3da?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8NXx8cGhvdG98ZW58MHx8MHx8fDA%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60'
         alt='Pic'
         class='h-[100px] w-[100px] rounded-full border-2 shadow-md'
        />
   </div>
   <p className='border-2'><span className='text-lg font-semibold'>dottt</span>  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).